# Flutter return widgets in for loop

Tags: flutter

My code below is working, but instead of returning multiple widgets based on the length of the list, it stops in the first round and after a lot of research and googling I understand that it stops because I'm returning a widget. So basically the for loop stops when it hits the "return".
And if I don't add the "return"  before the widget it return's nothing or it gives error saying that the "widget expecting a return type but nothing returning". So no "I think" I know th issue but I can't find the solution.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    for (var allAttributes in widget.allAttributes) {
      //print(allAttributes.name);
      bool attributeCheck;
      if(widget.attributes.length > 0){
        for(var attributes in widget.attributes){
          if(allAttributes.id == attributes.attributeId){
            return Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                    alignment: Alignment(-1.0, -1.0),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                      child: Text(
                        allAttributes.name + ':',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                    )),
                DropdownButton<Attributes>(
                  hint: Text("Select item"),
                  value: selectedUser,
                  onChanged: (Attributes Value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedUser = Value;
                    });
                  },
                  items: widget.attributes.map((Attributes attributes) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<Attributes>(
                      value: attributes,
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            attributes.value,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return Text('Nothing');
  }
```

I did try with the map but it didn't work too, Here's the code for the map:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    widget.allAttributes.map((AllAttributes allAttributes) {
      //print(allAttributes.name);
        widget.attributes.map((Attributes attributes){
          return Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                  alignment: Alignment(-1.0, -1.0),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                    child: Text(
                      allAttributes.name + ':',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                  )),
              DropdownButton<Attributes>(
                hint: Text("Select item"),
                value: selectedUser,
                onChanged: (Attributes Value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedUser = Value;
                  });
                },
                items: widget.attributes.map((Attributes attributes) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<Attributes>(
                    value: attributes,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          attributes.value,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ],
          );
        }).toList();
    }).toList();

    return Text('Nothing');
  }
```

Comment: you need to build an array of widgets then return that

Comment: And how is that please can you provide some code please. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Map method of list could be best solution for this type of situation.

It is really hard to change such big code without edit, so i showed how you can do in your case.

```
 List<int> _data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          child: Column(
        children: _data.map((e) {
          return Text(e.toString());
        }).toList(),
      )),
    );
  }
```

I still tried my best to change code. i hope following code work without any error.

Moreover, you was making list two time by wrapping list with list(for loop with for loop) so removed it.

```
  //print(allAttributes.name);
  return Column(
        children:
    widget.attributes.length>0? widget.attributes.map((Attributes attributes){
      return Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
              alignment: Alignment(-1.0, -1.0),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                child: Text(
                  allAttributes.name + ':',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              )),
          DropdownButton<Attributes>(
            hint: Text("Select item"),
            value: selectedUser,
            onChanged: (Attributes Value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedUser = Value;
              });
            },
            items: widget.attributes.map((Attributes attributes) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<Attributes>(
                value: attributes,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      attributes.value,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }).toList(): [Text('Nothing')]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I'm afraid your code didn't work, there was some errors. anyway I have added my own code which I tried with the map that didn't work too. If you could check that code I appreciate it. And for the list it's tow types of list that I'm comparing against each other, So i'm not making two lists. Thank you

Comment: What happen when you tried and there is no need to wrap list map twice. And also explain what exactly happen when you tried my solution.

Comment: After fixing the syntax errors, It's showing "nothing" widget.

Comment: @user2682025 i updated my answer check it and also add  print(allAttributes.name) output if this ans not work.

Comment: it's still showing "nothing" widget. and for the print(allAttributes.name), it's printing all the names in the list.

Comment: sorry i forgot to consider length if condition now check it will work i think. @user2682025

Comment: It's not working, I tried many ways, The only way it's returning the other widgets that I want to return instead of the "nothing" widget, is using the for loop but the for loop is stoping at the first round. It's driving me crazy I want to understand why the for loop in the flutter stops with the first return.

Comment: If you return anything from any widget or function the it will stop over there only and because of that it is not showing all the list. There is 2 ways to solve it first is create a empty list variable and keep adding widget to it and at the end return it. Second way is you can use map function as I show demo code. Updated code too, Actually return was missing from column.

Comment: I did try many ways with the map it's not working. I will try with the empty list I like that. I will let you know. thanks for helping.

Comment: @user2682025 check updated code may help you and try with map as i show demo code.

Comment: now it should definitely work. i check in my system too.

Comment: Thank you very much it's definitely work, I didn't reply soon because I was working on it to make it work with my entire code. thank you again